# What further clarity does my question need?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66208359/delete-rows-from-dataframe-if-column-value-does-not-exist-in-another-dataframe)  was closed because it "lacked clarity". Can somebody please clarify for me what further clarity is required? I have reviewed the question posting guidance yet still do not what extra information I need to include; please advise. I provided information that was sufficient to generate a correct response that solved my problem, so I do not understand what is wrong.

It was my first post on stack overflow and I did edit it once to improve it following the suggestion of one commenter, but it was closed even after the edits and a correct answer was submitted.

Comment: You apparently got a good answer, because you accepted it.  What's the problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am trying to understand why it was closed on the grounds of lack of details and clarity so that in future the questions I post I am sure to include sufficient details and clarity so they will not be closed (perhaps in those cases, before a good answer is received)

Comment: The question looks OK to me in its present form.  Closing is not a perfect system; you apparently got the answer you needed, so there's nothing more to see here.  Next time, just include the needed information in the question from the start.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I definitely got the answer I needed. The question was closed when in its present form though, which is what confused me. Okay re including the right information from the onset though. I will do my best. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that having an link to an image, with the hyperlink as simple [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vnGg.png) may not have helped; someone reading that could easily miss that. Especially when it wasn't actually visually in the question till 50 minutes later. I suspect a couple of the votes might have been from when the question *was* less clear. Close votes aren't cleared when you edit a post. You could have a poor question, get 2 votes, improve it (dramatically) get 1 more and it'll still be closed; even though the 2 original voters may well have not voted the same for the new version.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for highlighting that. I will use clearer hyperlinks in future. There was something stopping me from including the image directly myself at the time though, I think it was insufficient rep, so somebody added in the image for me. I did not realise multiple votes accumulate into a closure, but what you have said makes sense. My initial understanding was just that a single high-rep/rank user could choose to close a question, and since the closure happened after the edits I thought somebody was unhappy with the question even after the edits, with the question in its present form.

Comment: No your question was closed by 3 users, you can see this in the question [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66208359/timeline). Only mods can single handedly close questions, or certain users (known as "gold badgers") can single handedly close questions tagged with an area that they have a gold badge in as a duplicate (but not any of the other reasons)

Comment: "The question was closed when in its present form though, which is what confused me" - If I see the timeline the first close vote was cast when the question was still in unedited form and from there it just kept rolling in the close votes review queue I guess. You are suffering the consequences of a highly popular website; because there are so many questions coming in, moderation and quality voting is key to keep order in the chaos. If your question isn't spit polished right from the start... you are likely to experience this situation.

Comment: @Gimby that might not be the first vote, it's just a vote that was made via review. The first could have been before or after it as close votes via the question don't have their times shown in the timeline. Oddly, however, gnat is shown as the *last* voter on the question, but they definitely weren't.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your explanation about the timeline. I did not realise that before. It seems that the main issue is the sequence of votes in relation to edits. In conclusion, I suppose the answer to my question is simply to include the right info from the start, as suggested by others. I have a better idea of what "right" is now as well.